# SSIS trying to only load file if all rows are good

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I am trying to use a SSIS package to insert data from a file into a table but only if all the data in the file is good. I have read around and realise that I  can split my good data and bad data with a conditional split.

However I cannot come up with a way to not write the good data if there is some bad data rows.

I can solve my problem use a staging table. I just thought I would ask if I am missing a more elegant way to do this within SSIS package rather than load then transform with TSQL.

[image: Package Image]

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

SSIS way allows wrapping actions in a Transaction. According to your task, you need to count bad rows in the dataflow, and if there is at least one bad row - do nothing i.e. rollback.
Below is how I would do it in Pure SSIS. Create a sequence and specify TransactionOption=Required on it, move your dataflow to the sequence. Add Count Rows transformation to your bad rows dataflow and store its result to some variable. After DataFlow inside sequence - create conditional task link where you check whether bad_rowcount variable > 0, and on the next - do little script task which raise an error to roll back transaction.
Pure SSIS - yes! Simpler than using staging table - not sure.

Comment: Thanks I'm thinking I'll go with a staging table. Not sure if it will be an issue but I am not keen to have a long transaction open on this specific table.